# KeyListener in other class

Tags: java, jframe

I have issue with KeyListener, i want to separate keylistener functionality to other class so i have:

JGame.java

```
 package jgame;

import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class JGame extends JFrame {

    public JGame() {
        Actions act = new Actions();
        addKeyListener(act);
        setFocusable(true);
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {

        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        JGame keys_ = new JGame();
        frame.add(keys_);
        frame.setSize(600, 400);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);

    }
}
```

and Actions.java

```
package jgame;

import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;

public class Actions implements KeyListener {

    @Override
    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
    }

    @Override
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
        if (e.getKeyCode() == 32) {
            System.out.println("Pressed spacebar");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
    }
}
```

When i run this application netBeans consol say:
 "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: adding a window to a container
    at java.awt.Container.checkNotAWindow(Container.java:488)
    at java.awt.Container.addImpl(Container.java:1089)
    at java.awt.Container.add(Container.java:1003)
    at javax.swing.JFrame.addImpl(JFrame.java:564)
    at java.awt.Container.add(Container.java:415)
    at jgame.JGame.main(JGame.java:18)
Java Result: 1
"

Comment: please give use the Board class, please.

Comment: Board class was empty, mean without any methods, i check run without "frame.add(new Board());" and nothing changed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, your conflict is here:

```
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        JGame keys_ = new JGame();
        frame.add(keys_);
```

you can not add a Frame to an another JFrame, i suggest you to use the **JinternalFrame**:

You probable want to use a JDesktopPane, then set the content pane of your frame to the desktop pane:

```
JDesktopPane desktop = new JDesktopPane(); //a specialized layered pane
    createFrame(); //create first "window"
    setContentPane(desktop);
```

Try to make the **JGame as JinternalFrame**, than you can add it to your JFrame using **JDesktopPane**

[see How to Use Internal Frames](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/internalframe.html)

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to add a `JFrame` to a `JFrame` when you call

```
JFrame frame = new JFrame();
JGame keys_ = new JGame();
frame.add(keys_);
```

as `JGame` extends `JFrame`. This is not possible. One solution is to let `JGame` extend `JPanel` instead.

See [JFrame inside another JFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17287248/jframe-inside-another-jframe) for a reference.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot add Window Class into another window.

Because this class will be end GUI. You can add other components into it.