# Setvisible() won't work. Error location: variable qz of type QUIZIQ

Tags: java, swing, compiler-errors

The code for the quiz is in a javasource package named tview

```
package tview.quiz;

import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.event.*;
import java.util.*;

class  Quiz extends JFrame implements ActionListener{
        JPanel panel;
        JPanel panelresult;
        JRadioButton choice1;
        JRadioButton choice2;
        JRadioButton choice3;
        JRadioButton choice4;
        ButtonGroup bg;
        JLabel lblmess;
        JButton btnext;
        String[][] qpa;
        String[][] qca;
        int qaid;
        HashMap<Integer, String> map;

        Quiz(){
                  initializedata();
                  setTitle("Quiz Program");
                  setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                  setSize(430,350);
                  setLocation(300,100);
                  setResizable(false);
                  Container cont=getContentPane();
                  cont.setLayout(null);          
                  cont.setBackground(Color.GRAY);
                bg=new ButtonGroup();     
                choice1=new JRadioButton("Choice1",true);
                choice2=new JRadioButton("Choice2",false);
                choice3=new JRadioButton("Choice3",false);
                choice4=new JRadioButton("Choice4",false);
                bg.add(choice1);
                bg.add(choice2);
                bg.add(choice3);
                bg.add(choice4);
                lblmess=new JLabel("Choose a correct anwswer");
                lblmess.setForeground(Color.BLUE);
                lblmess.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.BOLD, 11));
                btnext=new JButton("Next");
                btnext.setForeground(Color.GREEN);                
                btnext.addActionListener(this);
                panel=new JPanel();
                panel.setBackground(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
                panel.setLocation(10,10);
                panel.setSize(400,300);
                panel.setLayout(new GridLayout(6,2));
                panel.add(lblmess);
                panel.add(choice1);
                panel.add(choice2);
                panel.add(choice3);
                panel.add(choice4);
                panel.add(btnext);
                cont.add(panel);
                setVisible(true);
                qaid=0;
                readqa(qaid);

        }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){

                    if(btnext.getText().equals("Next")){
                                if(qaid<9){

                                            map.put(qaid,getSelection());
                                            qaid++;
                                            readqa(qaid);
                                            }
                                else {
                                            map.put(qaid,getSelection());
                                            btnext.setText("Show answers");

                                         }
                                }
                    else if(btnext.getText().equals("Show answers"))
                                new Report();


        }



    public void initializedata(){
                    //qpa stores pairs of question and its possible answers
                    qpa=new String[10][5];

                    qpa[0][0]="Test";
                    qpa[0][1]="A";
                    qpa[0][2]="B";
                    qpa[0][3]="C";
                    qpa[0][4]="D";

                    //qca stores pairs of question and its correct answer
                    qca=new String[10][2];

                    //create a map object to store pairs of question and selected answer
                    map=new HashMap<Integer, String>();

                    }
    public String getSelection(){
                    String selectedChoice=null;
                    Enumeration<AbstractButton> buttons=bg.getElements(); 
                    while(buttons.hasMoreElements()) 
                    { 
                    JRadioButton temp=(JRadioButton)buttons.nextElement(); 
                    if(temp.isSelected()) 
                                { 
                                            selectedChoice=temp.getText();
                                } 
                     }  
                    return(selectedChoice);
        }


    public void readqa(int qid){
                    lblmess.setText("  "+qpa[qid][0]);
                    choice1.setText(qpa[qid][1]);
                    choice2.setText(qpa[qid][2]);
                    choice3.setText(qpa[qid][3]);
                    choice4.setText(qpa[qid][4]);
                    choice1.setSelected(true);
        }
    public void reset(){
                    qaid=0;
                    map.clear();
                    readqa(qaid);
                    btnext.setText("Next");
                    }
    public int calCorrectAnswer(){
                    int qnum=10;
                    int count=0;
                    for(int qid=0;qid<qnum;qid++)
                                if(qca[qid][1].equals(map.get(qid))) count++;
                    return count;
        }

    public class Report extends JFrame{
                    Report(){
                                setTitle("Answers");
                                setSize(850,550);
                                setBackground(Color.WHITE);
                                addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter(){
                                                        public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e){
                                                                    dispose();
                                                                    reset();
                                                        }
                                            });
                                Draw d=new Draw();                                  
                                add(d);
                                setVisible(true);
                                }


                class Draw extends Canvas{
                                public void paint(Graphics g){
                                            int qnum=10;
                                            int x=10;
                                            int y=20;
                                            for(int i=0;i<qnum;i++){
                                                        //print the 1st column
                                                        g.setFont(new Font("Arial",Font.BOLD,12));                                         
                                                        g.drawString(i+1+". "+qca[i][0], x,y);
                                                        y+=30;           
                                                        g.setFont(new Font("Arial",Font.PLAIN,12));                             
                                                        g.drawString("      Correct answer:"+qca[i][1], x,y);
                                                        y+=30;
                                                        g.drawString("      Your answer:"+map.get(i), x,y);
                                                        y+=30;
                                                        //print the 2nd column
                                                        if(y>400)
                                                        {y=20;
                                                          x=450;
                                                        }

                                            }
                                            //Show number of correct answers
                                            int numc=calCorrectAnswer();
                                            g.setColor(Color.BLUE);
                                            g.setFont(new Font("Arial",Font.BOLD,14));
                                            g.drawString("Number of correct answers:"+numc,300,500);


                                }
                    }

        }




}


 public class QuizIQ{

        public static void main(String args[]){

        Quiz qz = new Quiz();

        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setSize(300, 300); // Set the size of the window
        frame.add(qz);
        frame.setVisible(true);

        }


}
```

Then I have a JFrame called interface within my main package which should show the quiz when a button is clicked.

```
private void quizBttnActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt)       
{                                         
    new QuizIQ().setVisible(true);
}
```

I keep getting an error that says cannot find symbol,
symbol: method setVisible(boolean)
***location: variable qz of type QUIZIQ***

Could someone please help me figure this error out?

Comment: Java GUIs have to work on different OS', screen size, screen resolution etc.  using different PLAFs in different locales.  As such, they are not conducive to pixel perfect layout.  Instead use layout managers, or [combinations of them](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5630271/418556) along with layout padding and borders for [white space](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17874718/418556).

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). 2) Use a logical and consistent form of indenting code lines and blocks.  The indentation is intended to make the flow of the code easier to follow! 3) A single blank line of white space in source code is all that is *ever* needed.  Blank lines after `{` or before `}` are also typically redundant. 4) See [The Use of Multiple JFrames, Good/Bad Practice?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9554636/418556)

Answer (score 1):

The class Quiz contains your JFrame. You make the quiz visible by instantiating Quiz.

```
Quiz qz = new Quiz();
```

It extends JFrame and will show by itself. See it'sconstructor. It already calls setVisible().

Your class QuizIQ instead does not extend JFrame and by this does not have a method setVisible().

Comment: The button click event is in a separate JForm and the quiz doesn't seem to be showing after I click the button.

Comment: I tried this as well but it didn't work tview.quiz.QuizIQ qz = new tview.quiz.QuizIQ();

Comment: You cannot use a JFrame in another JFrame, see this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17287248/jframe-inside-another-jframe Use a JFrame for the actual Window and a JPane within the JFrame.

Comment: @Fuzzzzzel Thank you. I'll try that now.