# Jframe locked to the bounds of main jframe

Tags: java, swing, jframe

how can i make a window(JFrame) inside another window(JFrame) in java,and be bound to its width/heights limit of parent frame.if someone try to drag the new window out of main frame,it doesnt allow out of main frame.

Comment: JFrame seems like the wrong direction.  JPanels already do this.  Why not use that?

Comment: Is this what you mean?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17287248/jframe-inside-another-jframe Does This Help?

Comment: i saw some software that have a window bound to main frame with close button options. i tought it would be the Jframe, can it be manualy done to jpanels?

Comment: `JInternalFrame`/`JDesktopPane` is probably what you are looking for. See: [How to Use Internal Frames](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/internalframe.html).

Comment: Thanks pamarnath, thats what i was looking for.